# Can I allocate struct in heap memory like this

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
struct Rectangle 
{
    int length;
    int breadth;
};
```

This is the method that I know to allocate struct in heap memory.

```
struct Rectangle *p;

p = new Rectangle; 
   

 p->length = 20;

cout<<p->length;
```

Comment: Yes that allocates memory for a `Rectangle` (probably on a heap). You don't need `new struct Rectangle` though. Just do `new Rectangle`. It's not like in C where you have to `typedef` your `struct`s. They are `typedef`ined automatically in C++. Don't forget to `delete p;` afterwards.

Comment: Why don't you simply try that? Try this code on a compiler and check if it builds and runs.

Comment: did you face any issue or problem with the posted code?

Comment: @kiner_shah That something builds and runs doesn't imply it is correct/legal. Due to the concept of undefined behavior in C++, this can easily happen.

Comment: @DanielLangr, agree but I think building and running is the first step when learning some new concept.

Answer (score 4):

That allocates memory for your variable p into heap.

But using modern c++ you could use

```
 auto my_rectangle=std::make_unique<Rectangle>();
```

And you can forget to delete object as it will be deleted automatically.

Comment: Don't forget to `#include <memory>`

Comment: This might be misleading, especially for beginners. "That" does not allocate memory for `p`. It allocates memory (storage) for an object of type `Rectangle` and then it initializes an object of this type in the allocated storage. Memory allocation and object initialization are two different things and `new` expression in this form performs both. Moreover, `p` is a completely standalone object. Here, it is a pointer and its storage (memory) is allocated automatically. A pointer and an object it points to are two separate objects, which is often misunderstood by beginners.